# Rails 4 action => destroy calls update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

A call to destroy in rails 4 is throwing an error in #update. The update code, when called, works correctly, as does new / create.

The routes:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :pages
  end

match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

The controller:

```
class Admin::PagesController < ApplicationController

  layout 'admin'
  ...

  # PUT /pages/1
  # PUT /pages/1.xml
  def update
    logger.info("Starting update")
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])

    if @page.update_attributes(page_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Page updated successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'show')
    else
      @page_count = Page.count
      render('edit')
    end
  end

  def delete
    logger.info("Starting delete")
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    logger.info("Ending delete")
  end

  def destroy
    logger.info("Starting destroy")
    #page = Page.find(params[:id]).destroy
    @page.destroy
    logger.info("After destroy")
    flash[:notice] = "Page destroyed successfully."
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def page_params
      params.require(:page).permit(:sport, :name, :html_code, :permalink)
    end
```

The calling delete html.erb

```
<% @page_title = "Delete Page" %>

<%= link_to("<< Back to List", {:action => 'index'}, :class => 'back-link') %>

<div class="pages delete">
  <h2>Delete Page</h2>

  <%= form_for([:admin, @page], :url => {:action => 'destroy', :id => @page.id}) do |f| %>

    <p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this page?</p>

    <p class="reference-name"><%= @page.permalink %></p>

    <div class="form-buttons">
      <%= submit_tag("Delete Page") %>
    </div>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

The console:

```
Started GET "/admin/pages/delete/4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-07 12:56:38 -0800
Processing by Admin::PagesController#delete as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"4"}
Starting delete
  Page Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `pages`.* FROM `pages` WHERE `pages`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
Ending delete
  Rendered admin/pages/delete.html.erb within layouts/admin (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 8.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started PATCH "/admin/pages/4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-07 12:56:46 -0800
Processing by Admin::PagesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"3al7JBY9e1nl+xq7uH2m2S+sWDmhvFLhxuYeUp5ZKv8=", "commit"=>"Delete Page", "id"=>"4"}
Starting update
  Page Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `pages`.* FROM `pages` WHERE `pages`.`id` = 4 LIMIT 1
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param not found: page):
  app/controllers/admin/pages_controller.rb:85:in `page_params'
  app/controllers/admin/pages_controller.rb:59:in `update'


  Rendered /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (15.8ms)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, remove this route from your `config/routes.rb`:

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))', :via => [:get, :post]
```

This is a catch-all route and can cause misbehavior within your app. You should be using `resources` and friends, as per the [Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Secondly, all your form is really just a button to delete. You can accomplish this much more easily:

```
<p>Are you sure you want to permanently delete this page?</p>

<p class="reference-name"><%= @page.permalink %></p>

<%= button_to "Delete Page", [:admin, :page], :method => :delete %>
```

The `button_to` method creates a form, so that you don't have to. It's important to note here that this `button_to` is using `:method => :delete`, which will cause a `DELETE /admin/pages/4` route to be used; which goes to the `destroy` action within your controller.

Your form *was not* doing this before, it was submitting a `PUT` request to the same route, which goes to the `update` action, which is what you're seeing happening.

Comment: great answer, BTW your `Rails 4 Action` book is a real gem.

Comment: Thank you :) Steve Klabnik is doing all of the writing on that now.

Comment: Thank you. If I remove the catch-all match route, my link to get to the delete page from my index page fails: <%= link_to("Delete", {:action => 'delete', :id => page.id}) %>  with "No route matches {:action=>"delete", :id=>1, :controller=>"admin/pages"}"

Comment: @TomWillson: Define a proper route for that as per the routing guide.